# r regex mileage

Tags: regex, r

I'm having a hard time writing a regular expression for mileage. Mileage can take in any of the following form:

- 130,000 miles
- 130000 miles
- 130XXX miles
- 130,XXX miles
- 130k miles
- something else you can think off

For regex strategy, would be better to read miles first and then take the first word that precedes it. So miles would be read first and then maybe 130,XXX.

Comment: http://regexhero.com/ for your help. And tutorial/help here: http://www.regexbuddy.com/tutorial.html

Comment: What is it you want the outcome to look like?  Are you subbing or pulling out all the instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this regex `^\d+,?(\d|X|k)+\smiles$`